# Generating large pdf in javascript: browser kills hanging page

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I'm developping an image cutting application using javascript. The main goal is to cut an image into easily printable pieces and generate a pdf with said pieces. You can find the dev version online at http://framingapp.com/ and on github https://github.com/jmorel/framingapp

The image manipulation in itself works quite well, however when it comes to pdf generation, Chrome kills my page and displays the `aww snap` error message. I tried using both pdf generationg js libraries available out there, `jsPDF` and `ByteScoutPDF` but neither one are able to generate large pdf (and `ByteScoutPDF` not being opensource, I can't modify it to support larger resolution and various page sizes).

I figured the sheer size of the pdf I want to build makes the page hang, Chrome thinks it's an error and kills it. I thought of using webworkers to avoid this but couldn't make them work with jsPDF. The pdf objects seem to be too complicated to be passed as a web worker argument and since it relies heavily on the window element I can't include and use it from within the webworker.

My question is therefore: is there anyway of generating a large pdf in js without the browser killing the page ?

*Before anybody asks why I'm not doing the pdf generation server side: the image processing itself is kind of intensive and I don't want to overload the server with it; but the main reason is that I don't want people uploading images to the server: it's slow and unpractical for very large images. Not to mention the fact that I have little space available on my server.*

Comment: Is using someone else's server an option?  There are online systems that can generate PDF and you still have to send the images there, but you don't have to worry about the server-side issues yourself.